# "bundle install" fails even though bundler-1.1.3 is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to run "bundle install" and it seems to have an issue with finding the appropriate gemfile even though I installed the gem bundler. I'm not sure what to do from here. When I run "bundle install" I get this:

```
C:\Users\User1\Sites\simple_cms>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) x86-mingw32

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.3)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

So then I install the bundler gem which appears to install just fine.

```
C:\Users\User1\Sites\simple_cms>gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.1.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.1.3...
```

But even though the install for the bundler gem succeeded "bundle install" still fails:

```
C:\Users\User1\Sites\simple_cms>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) x86-mingw32

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.3)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

When I run "gem list" the bundler is definitely there:

```
C:\Users\User1\Sites\simple_cms>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.3)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.1)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.0, 1.5.4)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.18)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.3.4)
mysql2 (0.3.11 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
sass (3.1.16)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6 x86-mingw32)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.4)

C:\Users\User1\Sites\simple_cms>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove your `Gemfile.lock`. Then run `bundle check` and see the output. It may ask you to run `bundle install` again.

Comment: It still appears to be searching for rails 3.0.0, even though I have 3.2.3 installed. I should mention that I copied and pasted this project from exercise files for a tutorial. "bundle install" now outputs:  Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this m
achine.
Try running `bundle install`.

C:\Users\Ladder9\Sites\simple_cms>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) x86-mingw32

Comment: Don't copy and paste whole projects. Follow the tutorial. You'll learn faster with that.

Comment: What's in your `Gemfile`. Did you specify a precise version of your rails gem?

Comment: Thanks, in the Gemfile I just changed the line "gem 'rails', '3.0.0'" to "gem 'rails', '3.2.3'" and it works now.

Comment: Thanks man, your method (delete gemfile.lock then bundle check) saves my time :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your version of Rails (3.0.0) requires Bundler 1.0.0 -- you have a newer version.

You can install a specific version through gem install like this:

```
gem install bundler -v 1.0.0
```

Comment: I installed bundler v 1.0.0 but it still comes up with that error. Do I need to specifically unsinstall bundler 1.1.3 first, and if so, could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't copy and paste whole projects.

First of all learn to use `rvm` or `rbenv` so you don't encounter conflicts with ruby versions and gems.

if your tutorial uses rails 3.0, you can put in something like

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
```

in your Gemfile.

I suggest you install the latest rails version though and learn that.